# Feature Tools default cutoff_time

Tags: featuretools

If I didn't specify the `cutoff_time` which date it will be the reference for the primitive TIME_SINCE_LAST?

I cannot find it in the documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a cutoff time isn't provided, the cutoff time will get set to the current time using `cutoff_time = datetime.now()`

Comment: where can this be found? could you provide source?

Comment: https://github.com/Featuretools/featuretools/blob/master/featuretools/computational_backends/calculate_feature_matrix.py#L136